# How do I open my practice LAMP server to non-local connections?

Tags: connection, external, lamp

So I'm really green with setting up a server and I am trying to get some experience. I've set up a simple local LAMP server in Ubuntu Server on Virtual Box VM and been able to find my own resources up to this point, I just cant figure out how to allow external connections.

From what I have been able to find, I need to forward port 80 connections to my server machine's local ip within my router. Then I should be able to connect from outside my network by just using it's ip? I gather that I need to use a dns to pair my server with a domain name.

I just cant find a straight overview of the process and its driving me crazy!

Any resources would be great, unless what I have above is correct!

Comment: Basically correct, however watch out for two things. 1) The LAMP VM's IP changing if you're using DHCP. 2) Your internet service provider blocking access to port 80 at your IP (assuming home connection).

Comment: So I could fix 1) by setting up a static ip. I read about 2) but didnt understand how an ISP could block port 80 on my machine. Can I open it? Thanks

Comment: The issue is outside your local LAN. If I hit your website from my home, I use your external IP. For residential connections, some ISPs block access to common ports like 25, 80, etc before it would even get to your router and be forwarded to your LAMP server. If this is a problem, you can use a high non-standard port like 50000. Just need Apache to listen on that port and your router to forward it.